# Choppy scrolling in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with my micro website. When I scroll, it's nice and smooth in all browsers except Safari. When I do scroll in Safari, the content div jumps or moves frequently (it should stay in place) and makes the scrolling look choppy. Do you have any idea what could be wrong?

This is the website:
http://beta.dynamicdust.com

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I took a look and did see the "choppy" scrolling you mentioned (looking at it more, it was hit or miss - sometimes it was smooth, other times it was VERY choppy).

It seems you've got some performance issues with your `parallax` callback on Safari (though it wouldn't surprise me if it's some buggy implementation with Safari...)

One thing I would recommend is taking a look at `requestAnimationFrame` for webkit. For a test, I wrapped the logic to update the offsets in a `raf` (and cached the `window.pageYOffset` value) and it seemed smoother on my end.

```
function parallax(e) {
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame(function() {
        var offset = window.pageYOffset;
        a.style.top = (offset / 2) + "px";
        b.style.top = (offset / 2) + "px";
        textbox.style.top =- (offset * 0.7) + "px";
        textbox2.style.top =- (offset * 0.7) + "px";
    });
}
```

To be honest, you could probably use `raf` for all browsers (if they support it).

Another trick people use when animating elements is to accelerate the layer that the element you are animating is on. There are a few ways to do this, but the easiest is to use `-webkit-transition` and set `translateZ(0)`. It wouldn't hurt to add the two additional lines as well:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
```

Also, I noticed that some elements you offset (using `style`) are `position: relative` - Personally, I'd say that any element that's to be animated should be `position: absolute`. This will remove the element from the DOM, and offsetting it won't cause reflows to surrounding elements (which may contribute to your choppiness).

Edit - one other thing I noticed is that "choppiness/weirdness" happens when you encounter rubberbanding on safari (my guess are the negative values). That might be something you'll want to look at as well.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Jack! What an answer, very nice. It did help a a lot, however you're right with the rubber band in Safari. I did make the updates you suggested and the performance is much better, but I wasn't able to fix the rubber band issue. Could you help me with that?

Answer (score 14):

I haven't checked to see how my answer compares to Jack's, but I think the problem is that Safari attempts to be very power efficient. As a result, it is hesitant to enable hardware acceleration unless it needs to. A common trick that people use to force hardware acceleration is to place 
`-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);`
into the css for the divs which are moving. I tried it with the content class and it seemed a little better. You might try applying it to the other layers as well.

EDIT: I applied it to the left and right text holder divs as well, and the page seems just as smooth as Chrome now.

Comment: +Upvote - This is a good point Kevin (I was actually editing my answer to include this as well :) - Looks like there are multiple things Dominik could do to improve performance in general - this is definitely a huge one though!

Comment: Thanks, I liked your point about the DOM reflowing with `position:relative` . I did not know that.

Comment: Thank you, this a great improvement to the scrolling. I upvoted your answer, however I can't choose yours, as Jack is right with the rubber band scrolling in Safari which is now the last issue with the scrolling.

Answer (score 7):

Just jotting this down, as I came across this today with an overflow auto element:

The solution was to add this rule to whatever element the scrollbar shows up on:

`-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`

More detail can be found here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling

Answer (score 1):

Elements with heavy transitions on hover and active state can result in rendering issues.

In our case we had box-shadow transitions on some elements that were applied on hover. When the user scrolled the page and swiped the effected element, the transition got triggered. The browser then had to do the hard work of rendering the transition while scrolling.